# Python: After copying the list, expected integer added in the original list

Tags: python

```
mat=[[1,3,4,2],[6,7,8,4]]
```

```py
class Solution:
    def isSuperSimilar(self, n, m, mat, x):
        arr=mat[:]
        while x > 0: 
            for i,row in enumerate(arr):
                if i%2: 
                    arr[i].insert(0,row[-1])    #Rotate right if odd by 1 
                    arr[i]= row[:-1]
                    #print(arr[i])
                else:
                    arr[i]=row[1:]+ row[:1]     #Rotate left if even by 1 
                    #print(arr[i])
                
            x-=1
        print('ARR', arr) 
        print('MAT',mat)
```

```
MAT [[1, 3, 4, 2], [4, 6, 7, 8, 4]]                           
ARR [[3, 4, 2, 1], [4, 6, 7, 8]]
```

The original matrix was never changed nor did I assigned them directly as arr=mat
so that they have the same `id` but the original matrix had this last integer '6'.

What kind of bug is this? How I remove this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `arr=mat[:]` is a *shallow copy* - you only copied the outer, 2-element list, both `arr` and `mat` still share the same inner 4-element lists.  `copy.deepcopy()` is one possible solution.

Comment: Yes deepcopy worked . Thanks